# How can I perform an action after selecting an Option on a Select using Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to redirect my page when selecting an Option on a Select using Thymeleaf. My code is written as follows:

```
<select>
    <option th:each="size : ${pageSizes}" th:text=${size}  th:onclick="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/ingredient(size=${size})} + '\''"></option>
</select>
```

And, after inspecting it on Google Chrome, the HTML created is:

```
<select>
    <option onclick="window.location.href = '/ingredient?size=5'">5</option>
    <option onclick="window.location.href = '/ingredient?size=10'">10</option>
    <option onclick="window.location.href = '/ingredient?size=20'">20</option>
    <option onclick="window.location.href = '/ingredient?size=25'">25</option>
    <option onclick="window.location.href = '/ingredient?size=50'">50</option>
</select>
```

But nothing happens when a select a new Option. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onchange event on `select` tag instead of onclick.

```
<select th:onchange="'window.location.href = \'' + @{/ingredient} + '?size=\' + this.value ' ">
    <option th:each="size : ${pageSizes}" th:text=${size}  ></option>
</select>
```